# can we use magnifing glass functionality in indexed table for Viewing A..Z alphabets?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I have implemented index table which shows data alphabetically(A...Z).Can i show that alphabets(A..Z) using Magnifying glass?if yes then please share your idea how it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry there is not any inbuilt functionality for this. If you want to use it you can create custom images and set animation when user swipes the finger through table.